# Security Context with several elements on CubeJS

Tags: javascript, sql, backend, cube, cube.js

Currently working on **Cube.JS** and I'm building a cube within I want to **restrict the data** to an user based on his gender. So I end up with :

```js
cube(`Data`, {
    sql: `select * from my_table where ${SECURITY_CONTEXT.user_gender.filter(user_gender)}`,
    ...
```

as explained [here](https://cube.dev/docs/security/context)

But now I want to restrict the data to an user based on his **gender AND his age**, how should I proceed ? I was thinking about something like that...

```js
cube(`Data`, {
    sql: `select * from my_table where ${SECURITY_CONTEXT.user_gender.user_age.filter(user_gender,user_age)}`, //????
    ...
```

...but it seems weird to put two "attributes" `.user_gender.user_age.filter` to the `SECURITY_CONTEXT`

I hope someone has already tried something like that.
**Thank you!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `SECURITY_CONTEXT` twice:

```js
cube(`Data`, {
    sql: `select * from my_table where ${SECURITY_CONTEXT.user_gender.filter(user_gender)} AND ${SECURITY_CONTEXT.user_age.filter(user_age)}`,
    ...
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but in `SECURITY_CONTEXT.part1.filter(part2)`, the part2 correspond to the sql column we want to filter and part1 to the name of the element passed in the token ?